# Footer position fixed to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been unable to get my footer fixed to screen.  Meaning when the page is viewed I would like to see footer at all times.  I have tried position(fixed, absolute) but have been unable to solve.  I have searched the web, but am still having difficulty getting to stay at bottom of screen thanks in advance for any help

tried: `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`

```css
.bo-wrap {
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
}

.bo-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 25px;
}

.bo-footer-social {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.bo-footer-smap {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bo-footer-uonline {
  width: 300px;
  /* Account for margins + border values */
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bo-footer-power {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #636A7D;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bo-footer-copyright {
  text-align: center;
  color: #BDC3CF
}
```

```html
<div class="bo-wrap clr4">
  <div class="bo-footer">
    <div class="bo-footer-social"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bo-wrap clr3">
  <div class="bo-footer">
    <div class="bo-footer-smap">
      <a href="http://www.bangalionline.com/sitemap.php">Sitemap</a> | <a href="http://www.bangalionline.com/terms.php">Policy</a> | <a href="http://www.bangalionline.com/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bo-footer-uonline">
      <script id="_wautoy">
        var _wau = _wau || [];
        _wau.push(["small", "p6egqc1t5bze", "toy"]);
        (function() {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.async = true;
          s.src = "http://widgets.amung.us/small.js";
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        })();
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="bo-footer-power">
      Powered By JK - <a href="http://www.jobaerulkaes.com/">Web &amp Apps Developer</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bo-wrap clr4">
  <div class="bo-footer">
    <div class="bo-footer-copyright">&copy;2019 Timeless Consignment All rights reserved.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using the `position: fixed` in .bo-footer I guess whats missing is the `bottom: 0;`

Comment: you have 2 footers btw

Comment: Browser won't automatically understand where do you want to fix the footer. You need to provide bottom value to the fixed positioned element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the three footer div, class = wrapper, footer-wrapper

```
   <div class="wrapper footer-wrapper">
    <div class="bo-wrap clr4">
      <div class="bo-footer">
        <div class="bo-footer-social"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bo-wrap clr3">
      <div class="bo-footer">
        <div class="bo-footer-smap">
          <a href="http://www.bangalionline.com/sitemap.php">Sitemap</a> | <a
            href="http://www.bangalionline.com/terms.php">Policy</a> | <a
            href="http://www.bangalionline.com/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bo-footer-uonline">
          <script id="_wautoy">var _wau = _wau || []; _wau.push(["small", "p6egqc1t5bze", "toy"]);
            (function () {
              var s = document.createElement("script"); s.async = true;
              s.src = "http://widgets.amung.us/small.js";
              document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
            })();</script>
        </div>
        <div class="bo-footer-power">
          Powered By JK - <a href="http://www.jobaerulkaes.com/">Web &amp Apps Developer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bo-wrap clr4">
      <div class="bo-footer">
        <div class="bo-footer-copyright">&copy;2019 Timeless Consignment All rights reserved.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then styled the wrapper position absolute, width 100% and bottom set to 0:

```
.wrapper.footer-wrapper{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
}
```